# Use of the word 'relishing'

Tags: word-usage, speech

Recently when talking to a friend about the lack of elevators in Asia he told me.

> You should be relishing stairs

As a native English speaker the use of the word 'relishing' here sounded strange to me, although I can't quite figure out why, it seemed like a very odd thing to say in spoken English.

Why does it sound strange?
Is there anything wrong with this construction?

Comment: I like it!  Although it may be "strange" (unfamiliar) to your ear, it is a nice way of expressing enthusiasm for a mildly taxing (for many of us) activity.  Would "relishing taking the stairs" be more to your liking?

Comment: @hardmath not really, lol, but I relish taking the stairs might be slightly better.

Answer (score 4):

*Relishing* is a colourful and appropriate synonym for *liking*, but I would say it's only really appropriate to use to describe an action, not an object.

> verb
>
> 1. to savour or enjoy (an experience) to the full
> 2. to anticipate eagerly; look forward to
> 3. to enjoy the taste or flavour of (food, etc); savour
> 4. to give appetizing taste or flavour to (food), by or as if by the addition of pickles or spices

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/relish

> He relished the chance to show off his new skill.

I wouldn't eagerly anticipate or look forward to a staircase; but I might eagerly anticipate or look forward to climbing it.

Comment: Very interesting.  You may be right, but I had never considered it more appropriate to describe an action than an object.  OP's referenced phrase bothers me because I don't use relish so much and I tend to think of it in situations where _savoring_ might be used. Very interesting!

Comment: Yes, "relish" is mostly used in terms of eating, so it's a good synonym for savor.

Comment: @Mike and Jeffery Kemp, my thoughts exactly! Relish in my mind is most properly used in the context of food, "savouring stairs" sounds equally strange!